# OS X version of bringSubviewToFront:?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I need to replicate the function of bringSubviewToFront: on the iPhone, but I am programming on the Mac. How can this be done?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Haven't actually tried this out - and there may be better ways to do it - but this should work:

```
NSView* superview = [view superview];  
[view removeFromSuperview];  
[superview addSubview:view];
```

This will move 'view' to the front of its siblings

Comment: Probably inefficient, but it accomplishes what I wanted, so thanks.

Comment: It may be worth investigating using the `setSubviews:` method instead.

Answer (score 6):

Pete Rossi's answer didn't work for me because I needed to pop the the view to front when dragging it with the mouse.  However, along the same lines the following did work without killing the mouse:

```
CALayer* superlayer = [[view layer] superlayer];
[[view layer] removeFromSuperlayer];
[superlayer addSublayer:[view layer]];
```

Also, the following placed in a NSView subclass or category is pretty handy:

```
- (void) bringToFront {
    CALayer* superlayer = [[self layer] superlayer];
    [[self layer] removeFromSuperlayer];
    [superlayer addSublayer:[self layer]];
}
```

Comment: I came looking for the solution to this and, barring a kerfuffle because my hosting view was not layer backed, this worked a treat. Thank you for sharing it.

Answer (score 1):

also be sure to enable the layer for quartz rendering:

```
...
NSImageView *anImage = [[NSImageView alloc] initWithFrame:NSRectMake(0,0,512,512)];
[anImageView setWantsLayer:YES];
...
```

otherwise, your layer cannot be rendered correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Pete Rossi's answer works, but remember to retain the view when you remove it from the superview.

You can add this in a category on NSView :

```
-(void)bringSubviewToFront:(NSView*)view
{
    [view retain];
    [view removeFromSuperview];  
    [self addSubview:view];  
    [view release];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sibling views that overlap can be hard to make work right in AppKit—it was completely unsupported for a long time. Consider making them CALayers instead. As a bonus, you may be able to reuse this code in your iOS version.

Answer (score 0):

This is Swift 3.0 solution:

```
extension NSView {
    public func bringToFront() {
        let superlayer = self.layer?.superlayer
        self.layer?.removeFromSuperlayer()
        superlayer?.addSublayer(self.layer!)
    }
}
```